# Why shellcodes with jmp instruction work, and why doesn't the labels work inside a C wrapper?

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode, machine-code

I have two assembly codes like the one below

file: a.asm

```
section .text
global _start
_start: mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, mesg
        mov edx, 10
        int 0x80
        mov eax, 1
        int 0x80
mesg    db      "KingKong",0xa
```

and another assembly code

file: b.asm

```
section .text
global _start

_start: jmp mesg

prgm:   mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        pop ecx
        mov edx, 10
        int 0x80
        mov eax,1
        int 0x80
mesg:   call prgm
        db "KingKong",0xa
```

After taking the hex of these two codes and putting it inside this C wrapper

```
char *b = "\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x7d\x80\x04\x08\xba\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\x4b\x69\x6e\x67\x4b\x6f\x6e\x67\x0a";

char *b = "\xe9\x19\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x01\x00\x00\x00\x59\xba\x0a\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xe8\xe2\xff\xff\xff\x4b\x69\x6e\x67\x4b\x6f\x6e\x67\x0a";
int main()
{
        (*(int (*)(void))a)();
}
```

The first assembly code(`b`) prints 'KingKong' as expected but the second assembly code `a` print garbage. like the one shown

```
root@bt:~/Arena# ./a
�root@bt:~/Arena#
root@bt:~/Arena# ./b
KingKong
```

output generated by `a` (first one) is this `�` weird character, while the second one (`b`) prints `kingkong` as expected.
Now could someone exlain why was the second assembly code is working while the first isn't .

**EDIT:**
From the answer I see that the first program hard-codes the address. Even the second approach uses labels, like `jmp mesg`, now wont this instruction make the program very similar to the first, aren't they both the same cos they use `labels` to decide the location. All I know is, to have the code position independent we need to use the `esp` or the `ebp` registers with relative addressing scheme. Wont the second program's jmp instruction make it just the same like the first one.

Comment: Saying something "does not work" is unhelpful. What did you expect it to do? (I would expect it to overflow the stack and fault.) What did it do?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oops I forgot the output, my bad. I've included the output now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The address of `mesg` can vary depending on how your program is laid out in memory.**

The following will hard-code a specific address and will not work reliably (or at all):

```
    mov ecx, mesg
```

For reference, the first approach hard-codes the following address:

```
    mov ecx, 0x804807d
```

The second approach does work because it figures out the address of `mesg` at runtime, using the return address of a `call` instruction.

Put another way, the first version only works if loaded at a specific address whereas the second is [position-independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

It is worth noting that the `jmp` and the `call` instructions that appear in the second version use *relative addressing*, meaning that the opcodes specify the *distance* to the target rather than the *address* of the target. This makes these instructions work regardless of where they are placed in memory.

If you examine the opcodes, you'll see that the `jmp` is encoded as

```
e9 19 00 00 00
```

(i.e. jump 0x19, or 25<sub>10</sub>, bytes forward), and the `call` is encoded as

```
e8 e2 ff ff ff
```

where `0xffffffe2` is a small negative number (-30).

Comment: @NPE I have made a small edit to my code, would you please help me out with the edit !!!

Comment: `jmp` and conditional jumps, and `call` use relative addressing. we write `jmp target` and it disassembles as "jmp address_of_target", but if you look at the opcodes/operands it's "jmp distance_to_target". That's the difference.

Comment: @vikkyhacks: I've expanded the answer to address the additional question.